# Which method performs fastest while adding an attribute in jQuery, using attr() method, passing attributes as a key-value object, or direct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I know three ways of adding a href attribute which contains a relative link in jQuery: using (1) .attr(), (2) attributes as key-value pair in an argument, or (3) direct writing (you might know other methods, please tell in your answer for me to learn).

1. Using .attr()

It will look something like below using this method.

```
var link = "relative-link.html";
$("<a/>").attr("href",link);
```

2. Using argument

Like this:

```
var link = "relative-link.html";
$("<a/>", {href: link});
```

3. Direct

Like this:

```
var link = "relative-link.html";
$("<a href=" + link + ">");
```

So, which is faster performance wise among those method? Why I should choose one method over the others. Also consider adding other attributes such as `class` and which method should be preferred when adding multiple attributes in one go.

Please tell me which method is better and in which case with proper reasoning. Thanks!

Comment: I'd prefer 2nd method, saves one function call and better than using string

Comment: @Tushar What do you think about the third one?

Comment: The second is the easiest to read and can be used with more than one attribute.

Comment: Bad practice. already told `better than using string`

Comment: @Tushar I see. Would you tell me, why using string is worse?

Comment: It is not true that method 2 is the fastest, though upfront it saves a function call which improves upon the readability. Read the detailed answer below which is based on jQuery's code.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an interesting question. I looked into jQuery's code on github and suggest you should look at the same [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/5153b5334eb2c8317372b46209bd9d092a91afdc/src) for purely learning purposes (and also the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes))

Here are my findings

In General
Method called when you are creating the element i.e. when you write `$(".....")` is `init`. [Code here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5153b5334eb2c8317372b46209bd9d092a91afdc/src/core/init.js#L18) . It internally uses `parseHTML` [method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/core/parseHTML.js#L37). ParseHTML for simple single tag HTML would just use `document.createElement` ([here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/core/parseHTML.js#L34)) and for complex HTML builds the DOM nodes. Two of the arguments accepted by `init` function are `selector` and `context` - `selector` being the HTML string and `context` being the attributes object that you pass as an argument in the second method you have pointed out.

Method called when adding attributes is `attr`. [Code Here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5153b5334eb2c8317372b46209bd9d092a91afdc/src/attributes/attr.js#L13)

**Method 1**
`$("<a/>").attr("href",link);`
Here jQuery first creates an element. And then separately attempts to add the attributes to the created elements. The `init` function receives no `context` argument. It just adds a basic `<a>` element using `document.createElement` internally. [This](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5153b5334eb2c8317372b46209bd9d092a91afdc/src/core/init.js#L60) part of the code is never executed and the newly created object is returned. The `attr` method is then called on the created jQuery wrapped DOM object. **Thus `init` is called once and `attr` is also called once.** Even if you were to pass multiple attributes in the same `attr()` call, it would still be called once.

**Method 2**
`$("<a/>", {href: link});`
Here jQuery attempts to add the attributes while creating the DOM element. It now receives the `context` which is the attributes to be added to the element. It iterates over this attribute map [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5153b5334eb2c8317372b46209bd9d092a91afdc/src/core/init.js#L60) calling the `attr()` method for each of them separately (which can be seen [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5153b5334eb2c8317372b46209bd9d092a91afdc/src/core/init.js#L67)). This is equivalent to `$("<a>").attr(key, val).attr(key1, val1).attr(key2, val2);` **Thus `init` is called once but internally `attr` is called multiple times.**

**Method 3**
`$("<a href=" + link + ">");`
Here jQuery again doesn't receive any `context` arguments. It just receives a plain HTML string that has to be parsed. In such cases as per the documentation, if the HTML is more complex than a single closing tag, jQuery builds the DOM nodes using the `buildFragment` method ([code here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/manipulation/buildFragment.js)) and uses the `innerHTML` method to insert the HTML that you passed to insert it in the document. This happens in the `parseHTML` [function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/core/parseHTML.js#L37) of jQuery which internally calls `buildFragment`. **So only `init` is called once which internally has to build the node. No call to `attr`.**

**Readability**
So method 2 actually wraps the call to `attr` in the same DOM element creation call and provides a more readable form. However IMHO method 1 has the same readability as method 2 and should be faster than method 2. In method 3 (as performance tests would later indicate), building the DOM node takes a lot of time because everything has to go through the `buildFragment` phase which is not the case for method 1 and 2 where single tag html is passed and `document.createElement` is used straight away.

**Performance**
For a single element creation, you would hardly notice any difference in execution time. It would take less than a few ms always. I created this test for 100,000 elements, to see if there is any difference. Comment out the method that you want to test to get the time of execution.

**Method 1:** time taken: 400-600ms (fastest)
**Method 2:** time taken: 550-700ms
**Method 3:** time taken: 2700-2900ms (slowest as expected)

The times could vary, but the trend would remain the same. The test is available here http://jsfiddle.net/6ko59joo/2/. Experiment with it.

**Alternative: No jQuery**

Undiscussed so far is the option to leave jQuery and use vanilla JS. In that case, the performance on the above test jumps to 70-80ms. The code for this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a'); 
a.href = link;
```

For your consideration, it is also included in the jsFiddle.

This is based on my understanding and tests. I would like to be corrected if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Good answer. At the end of the day, vanilla JS will always be faster though: `var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = link;` comes out at 70ms

Comment: Can you edit the answer with the updated test. Will be great for everyone.

Comment: Done. See the bottom paragraph.

Comment: Given the example, using Vanilla JS is much faster. Thanks for the addition, Jorg. I have been experimenting by chaining the three method with addClass(). The first method is the fastest, with the gap between the second method 100ms. Thank you for your detailed explanation @RahulNanwani.

Comment: @Matt Sadewa Bear in mind that the 70ms is for the creation of 100.000 links. In an actual app the difference is negligible - fraction of a millisecond. (If you want to access element classes in vanilla, check `a.className`)

Comment: Yep! Thanks for the suggestion! I have some element manipulations to do with methods like this. If I choose the faster ones, it will save many ms's.